# Как создать ссылки из значений массива

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется массив произвольной длины, т.е. каждый раз значения в нем разные и их кол-во - тоже.
Нужно создать на странице столько ссылок `<a></a>`, сколько значений есть в массиве. А их адресом должны стать значения из массива.

Пример:

```
var mass = [1, 123, 3, 7];

<div id="link_box"></div>
```

Получиться должно следующее:

```
<div id="link_box">
    <a href="1"></a>
    <a href="123"></a>
    <a href="3"></a>
    <a href="7"></a>
</div>
```

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Создаём массив `<a>` элементов (а точнее jQuery обёрток над ними) из `mass`, после чего добавляем их к `#link_box`:

```js
var mass = [1, 123, 3, 7];
var links = mass.map(function(href) {
  return $("<a>", { href: href, text: href });
});
$("#link_box").append(links);
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="link_box"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

`text: href` добавлено для наглядности примера.

Comment: спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

Либо чуть более простой пример без jquery

HTML:

js:

```
var mass = [1, 123, 3, 7];
var res;
for (var i of mass) {
 if (res !== undefined) {
     res += '<a href="' + i + '">' + i + '</a>';
   } else {
     res = '<a href="' + i + '">' + i + '</a>';
   }
}
var resDiv = document.getElementById("link_box");
if (resDiv) {
  resDiv.innerHTML = res;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e1ceyfev/1/

Comment: , да, не заметил поправил

Comment: спасибо! Без Jquery тоже пригодится!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var links = ['https://ya.ru', 'https://google.com', 'https://mail.ru'];
var a = document.createElement('a');
for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  link = a.cloneNode();
  link.href = links[i];
  link.innerHTML = links[i];
  link.className = 'denis';
  document.querySelector('#wrapper').appendChild(link);
}
```

```css
.denis{
  margin: 22px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Тоже все возьму на заметку!

Comment: кстати вот интересно, а можно в эту конструкцию добавить все ссылкам один класс?

Comment: Денис, можно)))

Comment: спасибо большое! =) К сожалению массивы - моя слабая сторона. Пошел просвещаться дальше)

Comment: Вообще, чтото советовать дело не хорошее))), но  посоветую...)))
1) - посмотри это  - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4FUjiQtNWkM&index=1&list=PLLvTAhHe8AYCQ52tXkjdKKPDjTP35bxKl
2) - потом это - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=43S4xL_Mong&list=PLLvTAhHe8AYBZKl_b6DP-bikdx8XqNCY4   
со всем уважением к лектору, но дядька нудный, но подает все профессионально. А когда будешь понимать общюю картину   -  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H6G63NKRSi8&list=PL363QX7S8MfSxcHzvkNEqMYbOyhLeWwem
 и вот это  -  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jGm-hcQBGlM&list=PLpY_9m7gHQDiwYLqQJotfN7nCm7I7jE60

Comment: а вот за совет отдельное спасибо =) С огромным удовольствием посмотрю!